# M2 | Is there any observer we can call with customer token generation API?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, token

I want to perform custom operation by getting customer information when a customer token is generated using API.

> `rest/V1/integration/customer/token`

Is there a way in magento I can get customer data when a token is returned as result of above API?

Or we can do this by any plugin?